# Hangman - when I enter a wrong letter, the message system index out of range appears

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a hangman game in the console app but got a message *index out of range*.
The image below shows that I can enter a letter. If I enter a wrong letter I can enter a new letter after entering a new letter I get the message system out of range.
I think the error can be found within the method public bool `raadletter` (char letter).
This program contains 2 classes, the first class is the `galgjespel` class (hangmangame) and the second class is the `program` class.

[image]

//I got this stacktrace value
~
error message
  at galgje2.GalgjeSpel.Raadletter(Char letter) in C:\Users\surface pro\source\repos\week3opdracht1\galgje2\Galgjespel.cs: line 37
  at galgje2.Program.Speelgalgje(GalgjeSpel galgje) in C:\Users\surface pro\source\repos\week3opdracht1\galgje2\Program.cs: line 128
  at galgje2.Program.Start() in C:\Users\surface pro\source\repos\week3opdracht1\galgje2\Program.cs: line 28
  at galgje2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\surface pro\source\repos\week3opdracht1\galgje2\Program.cs: line 14
~

//

```
 class GalgjeSpel
    {       

         public string secretWord;
        public string guessedWord;
        public void Init(string secretword)
        {
          this.secretWord = secretword;
           this.guessedWord="";
            char[] letter = new char [secretword.Length];
            for (int i =0; i< letter.Length; i++)
            {
                this.guessedWord += ".";
            }
        }
        public bool Raadletter(char letter)
        {

            char[] guesses = guessedWord.ToArray();

            guessedWord = "";
            if (secretWord.Contains(letter))
            {
                for(int i=0; i<secretWord.Length; i++)
                {
                    // somewhere on this place i get the index out of range message
                    if (secretWord[i]==letter)
                    {  
                        guesses[i] = letter;
                    }                 
                }
                foreach(var element in guesses)
                {
                    guessedWord += element;
                    if (element!='.')
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{element} ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write($". ");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine();
               // return true;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("letter does not match secretword");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
                Console.ResetColor();

            }

            return false;

        }
    }

////

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program myProgam = new Program();
            myProgam.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
        void Start()
        {
            GalgjeSpel galgje = new GalgjeSpel(); 
            galgje.Init("eetlepel");

            List<string> woordenlijst = WoordenLijst();
           string nieuwwoord= SelecteerWoord(woordenlijst);
            galgje.Init(nieuwwoord);

           ToonWoord(nieuwwoord);Speelgalgje(galgje);

            //Console.WriteLine("Het geheime woord is: " + galgje.geheimWoord);
            //Console.WriteLine("Het geraden woord is: " + galgje.geradenWoord);
        }
        List <string> WoordenLijst()
        {
            List<string> Woordenlijst = new List<string>();
            Woordenlijst.Add("slapen");
            Woordenlijst.Add("poepen");
            Woordenlijst.Add("eten");
            Woordenlijst.Add("vakantie");
            Woordenlijst.Add("reizen");
            return Woordenlijst;
        }
       string SelecteerWoord(List<string> woorden)
        {
            GalgjeSpel gaglje = new GalgjeSpel();

            Random rnd = new Random();
           int randomwoord = rnd.Next(1, 5);
            string nieuwwoord = woorden[randomwoord];
          gaglje.secretWord = nieuwwoord;

            return nieuwwoord;
        }

        void ToonWoord(string woord)
        {
            GalgjeSpel galgje = new GalgjeSpel();

            Console.Write($"The secret word is : ");
            char[] letter = woord.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i< woord.Length; i++)
            {
                galgje.secretWord += letter[i];
                Console.Write($"{letter[i]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); 

            Console.Write("the guessed word is : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < woord.Length; i++)
            {
                galgje.guessedWord += (". ");
                Console.Write(". ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        void ToonLetter(List<char> letters)
        {
            Console.Write("the letters entered are : ");
            foreach (var element in letters)
            {

                Console.Write($" {element} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        char LeesLetter(List<char> geheimeletters)
        {

            char letter;
            do
            {  Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("enter a letter : ");
                 letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               return letter;

            } while (geheimeletters.Contains(letter));
                {

                }

        }
        bool Speelgalgje(GalgjeSpel galgje)
        {
            //char lijst van ingevoerde letters
            List<char> ingevoerdeLetters = new List<char>();

            // char lijst van geheime letters
            List<char> geheimeletters = new List<char>();

            // zet elke geheime letter in een char array
            char[]geheimewoord = galgje.secretWord.ToArray();

            // voeg elke char letter toe aan lijst van geheime letters
            for (int i=0; i<geheimewoord.Length; i++)
            {
                geheimeletters.Add(geheimewoord[i]); 

                if (galgje.guessedWord == galgje.secretWord)
                 {
                      return true;
                 }
                 else
                  {  char letter = LeesLetter(geheimeletters);
                      ingevoerdeLetters.Add(letter);
                      ToonLetter(ingevoerdeLetters);
                      galgje.Raadletter(letter);

                     }

            }return false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be easier for people to help answer the question if you also included the error message and stack trace. That would help point to the line of code where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: i have added a picture with the error message

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace as text into the question. You can see the full stacktrace (and copy it) if you click on the tiny magnifying glass right or the stacktrace

Comment: thanks i have added the stacktrace as text just like you asked

Comment: When an index is out of range, it usually means that the value you're trying to get in the array is bigger or smaller than the array itself. Make sure the selected value in the array never gets bigger than the array.

Comment: Soo, what is line 37 in the file where the RaadLetter exists?

Comment: line 37 is 
                        guesses[i] = letter;

Comment: Are you sure that `guessedWord` (or its derived `guesses`) is at least as long as `secretWord`?

Comment: i think so but am not sure

Comment: So find out. How? Read that "How to debug" page, linked above - not because we are lazy, but because that way you learn ("give a fish" versus "teach to fish" principle)

Comment: i know but i am doing a lecture and the next lecture is error handling so i need to complete this course first before i can move on to the error handling lecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the code before the point of the exception

```
public bool Raadletter(char letter)
{

    char[] guesses = guessedWord.ToArray();

    // Here guessedWord is truncated
    guessedWord = "";

    // Now if the letter is not in the secretword you don repopulate the guessedword
    // So at the next loop the code builds a guesses array 
    // that doesn't match anymore to the secretWord length
    if (secretWord.Contains(letter))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (secretWord[i] == letter)
            {
                guesses[i] = letter;
            }
        }
        // Here you rebuild the guessedWord, but only if you have a match
        foreach (var element in guesses)
        {
            guessedWord += element;
            ....
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // fail messages
    }
```

The solution is to close the if and rebuild the guessedWord in each case

```
    char[] guesses = guessedWord.ToArray();
    guessedWord = "";

    if (secretWord.Contains(letter))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (secretWord[i] == letter)
            {
                guesses[i] = letter;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach(var element in guesses)
    {
         guessedWord += element;
         .....
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much it helped me out a lot your the best :).